# Software Evaluation and Purchase Sysetm

Tags: java, online-payment

I am writing a program in Java that I would like to sell and also release a 30-day evaluation copy of. I have access to a website to optionally host some portions of licensing but would prefer to not handle credit card processing myself.

What are some of the best options to issue a trial version of the software that will take a registration code that can be purchased on a website?